# Error 330 in Silverpop API when calling SaveMailing

Tags: php, mailing

I am trying to call the function SaveMailing to save an HTML template to the silverpop server, I copied the code from the documentation, double checked my list IDs and everything, still i get error 330 which i can't find in any documentation to the silverpop API.

Answer (score 0):

Error 330 is an "Invalid Path" error. In your XML request, make sure that the correct path is in the <FolderPath> XML node. If you have the template in your Shared folder, make sure the XML node reads <FolderPath>/Shared</FolderPath>. If you have the template in a deeper directory, the same applies. For a template in /Shared/dir1/dir2/, it should be <FolderPath>/Shared/dir1/dir2</FolderPath>.